# In app products link not displaying in android developer page in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i hava a problem in in-app billing in my developer page below Application name In-App Products link not displaying,how can i get it please any one solve my problem....

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference says ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html)):

> The In-App Products link appears only if you have a Google Checkout
>   merchant account and an application's manifest includes the
>   **com.android.vending.BILLING** permission.

Comment: thanks for u r response...i have account in Google Checkout merchant and i also mention com.android.vending.BILLING permision in manifestfile but In-App Products link not appear.

Comment: Have you signed the app too?... Sorry about the stupid questions, but I ran the dungeons example time ago and it worked fine...

Comment: In Google Checkout merchant account is free or payable

Comment: It's free. You even don't need to add your bank data for make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But now my merchant account and play account are linked and I can see In-App purchase products link.

Guess it was a bug on google play and they rectified it.

Comment: ok how can i get In-App purchase products link give any suggestion

Comment: In Google Checkout merchant account is free or payable